# Почему webpack --watch из Docker-контейнера не видит изменённые файлы проекта

Tags: docker, npm

Есть Docker с node 16

```
FROM node:16.20.2

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y bash
```

И есть файл docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  apache:
    build:
      context: docker/apache
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "80:80"
  node:
    build: docker/node
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
```

Я запускаю проект командой

```
docker-compose up --build
```

После чего запускаю контейнер с node, устанавливаю зависимости и запускаю watch файлов с помощью webpack

```
docker-compose run --rm node bash;
:/var/www/html# cd vue
:/var/www/html/vue# npm ci
:/var/www/html/vue# npm run watch
```

package.json выглядит так

```
...
"scripts": {
    "watch": "webpack --watch -d"
  }
...
```

Но при изменении файлов .vue пересборка не происходит. В чем может быть проблема?
Так же не могу запустить с хостовой машины watch пишет следующее

```
"webpack" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

P.S работаю на Windows

Comment: [В WSL2 это сломано](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4739)

Comment: @andreymal Очень грустно. Спасибо большое за информацию